# CSS Radial Gradient browser differences

Tags: css, radial-gradients

I have a really simple CSS radial gradient, which looks significantly different in different in Safari and others:

```
<style>
  body {
     background: #000;
  }
  div {
    height: 200px;
    width: 200px;
    background-image: radial-gradient(100px, #1493a4 0%, transparent 100%);
  }
</style>

<div></div>
```

Any ideas, how I could make them all look like the Safari version?

[image: Screenshot of Safari] [image]

```
Safari                         Firefox
```

Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/2234zy6o/3/

Comment: Can you include screenshots of output from Safari and the other browser so that we can verify if we see the same problem?

Comment: Just added them. :-)

Comment: Seems very weird. I checked on Safari (iOS), Chrome (Windows) and I see the same behavior. Chrome works like the Firefox output whereas Safari doesn't.

Comment: Seems like Safari uses something like ease-in for the gradient, but I cannot find an option to set that explicitly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally found a simple solution: Safari needs an own style:

```
background-image: -webkit-radial-gradient(#1493a4, transparent);
```

Just make sure to add it **after** the standard definition, other browsers then use the standard one and ignore the `-webkit` one, while Safari sees the first but then finds `-webkit` and ignores the standard.

But it's not quite the same, nevertheless. So I did some 'interpolation' and added some stops:

```
background-image: -webkit-radial-gradient(100px,
   #1493a4 0%,
   rgba(20,147,164,0.4) 40%,
   rgba(20,147,164,0.2) 55%,
   transparent 100%
);
```

It's still not the same but quite similar - at least I can live with it.